# How can I realize the following pattern matching in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

On a given list, I want to design a pattern matching case, which looks like this `a::b::c`
`a` shall be treated as a single element but `b` shall be treated as n Elements. `c` is  a specific type. Furthermore, I want to keep working with `a`, `b`, and `c`
So, is there any way to design a pattern which is built-up like this `1element::nelement::type`

Comment: You can't. There's no independent "middle part" of a list. Lists just have a head and a tail, with the tail itself being a list containing a head and tail and so on, recursively.

Comment: This also looks a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: okay thanks, I am going to overthink my way of tackling the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is no "middle" element on pattern matching of lists.

The following pattern:

```
| "lorem" :: "ipsum" :: rest -> ...
```

will match a list of strings with **at least** 2 elements matching, respectively,
`"lorem"` and `"ipsum"` and will bind `rest` to the rest of the list.

Using:

```
| "lorem" :: "ipsum" :: [] -> ...
```

you are going to match a list with **2 elements, exclusively**, that match `"lorem"`
and `"ipsum"`.

If you want to use pattern matching on the last element, you can do it with

```
match List.rev list with
| last_element :: _ -> ...
```

but you need to have a good reason to do it, because there are better/faster
ways to access the last element.